# O que é cálculo Lambda?

Tags: matemática

Ouvi sobre esse assunto uma vez, mas não compreendo a relação dele com programação. Onde eu poderia aplicar esse conhecimento em desenvolvimento?

Comment: É a base matemática da [programação funcional](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tags/programa%c3%a7%c3%a3o-funcional/info).

Answer (score 3):

## Cálculo λ

O cálculo λ se constitui de uma única regra de transformação, substituição de variável e um único esquema de definição de função. Ele foi introduzido na década de 1930 por Alonzo Church como uma maneira de formalizar o conceito de computabilidade efetiva. Também é considerado como menor linguagem de programação universal, no sentido de que qualquer função computável pode ser expressa e avaliada usando o formalismo desse cálculo.

Se você for um pouco mais a fundo, verá os primeiros resultados da teoria da computação foram desenvolvidos utilizando os formalismos da máquina de Turing e do cálculo λ. O conceito central no cálculo λ é a *expressão*, onde um identificador, ou seja, um "nome" ou "variável" são identificados por letras *a, b, c, …*. Uma expressão é definida como  `<expression> := <name> | <function> | <application>` ou `<function> := λ <name>.<expression>`, por exemplo.

### Exemplos

```
(+ 4 5)
(+ 4 5) = 9
```

As aplicações de funções no lambda cálculo são escritas no formato prefixo.

```
λx.(x + 1)
```

A expressão pode ser lida assim: "função de x a qual (.) adiciona x a 1". Algumas vezes costuma-se usar operadores sempre prefixados, e neste caso se escreveria (+ x 1).

```
(λx. + x 1)
```

"função de x que (.) incrementa x de 1"

O λ determina que existe uma função, e é imediatamente seguido por uma variável, denominada parâmetro formal da função

#### Onde eu poderia aplicar esse conhecimento em desenvolvimento?

Acho que o maior valor agregado seria o conhecimento. Não sei afirmar onde você poderia aplicar Cálculo λ, mas muita coisa que existe hoje foi feita a partir da formalização desse cálculo. Por exemplo, John McCarthy estendeu o cálculo λ para construir a primeira linguagem da família Lisp.

#### Referências:

- [https://www.di.ubi.pt/~desousa/2013-2014/CF/apresentacao-lambda.pdf](https://www.di.ubi.pt/%7Edesousa/2013-2014/CF/apresentacao-lambda.pdf)
- https://www.inf.fu-berlin.de/lehre/WS03/alpi/lambda.pdf
- [http://www.inf.ufsc.br/~j.barreto/PF/CalLambda.htm](http://www.inf.ufsc.br/%7Ej.barreto/PF/CalLambda.htm)